# Conditional Expectation given the following equations

Tags: conditional-expectation, lognormal-distribution

Suppose you have a Log-Normal model with:

$\log\left(x_t\right) = \mu_t + \varepsilon_t$

$\mu_{t+1} = \mu_t + \delta_t$

$\delta_{t+1} = \delta_t + \gamma_t$

where $\varepsilon_t \sim \text{NID}\left(0, \sigma^2_{\varepsilon}\right)$, $\gamma_t \sim \text{NID}\left(0, \sigma^2_{\gamma}\right)$ and $s_t = e^{\mu_t}$.

How do you calculate the conditional expected value $\mathbb{E}\left(x_t|s_t\right)$?

Comment: If you exponentiate both sides of your first equation and then consider the conditional expected value you are interested at, what is left to wonder?

Comment: Yes, this would be the first point, but then I would like to go on and come to a result, but I get stuck. $\mathbb{E}\left(x_t|s_t\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(e^{\mu_t + \varepsilon_t}|e^{\mu_t}\right) = ...$